# MySQL installation on a Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, command-line, installation

I've had some issues with install MySQL on my MacBook Pro (early 2011, OS X version 10.11.6). I've run the disk image a few times, each time a successful installation. From what I understand, though, I'm supposed to be provided with a temporary password upon installation, and I never am.

After installation, I enter my Terminal and type `mysql`, but I only ever get the following response:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? I know very little about command line coding, so the more detail you could provide the better.

Please let me know if there's any more information about this whole installation process that I need to provide, and I'll be sure to post it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should login to mysql client as follows -

> mysql -uroot -p

Given you have kept root as the username.

Comment: This results in the following error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` Now apparently I have a password, and I'm still running into issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are NOT provided with a default password upon completion, this should do the trick:

Quoting [First google hit.](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/)

1 - Stop MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

2 - Start it in safe mode:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

3 - This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished so open another shell/terminal window, and log in without a password as root:

```
mysql -u root
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

4 - Change the lowercase ‘MyNewPass’ to what you want – and keep the single quotes.

```
\q
```

5 - Start MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Thats it, now your root password will be updated.

Comment: `ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!` The regular Google solutions haven't worked so far....

Comment: @Yehuda At which step? PS Sorry for late reaction, exams and stuff.